# Indicating Interesting tags in the Recent Tags list

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, recent-tags

Would it make sense to somehow highlight the user's Interesting Tags in the list of Recent Tags on the homepage?

Use case: "Hmm, there have been some active C++ questions lately, let's have a look at them." Without the highlight, the interesting tags are likely to drown in the noise.

Comment: Originally I was ambivalent-to-negative on this, but then I remembered that other users probably have a lot of interesting tags, so they can't really afford to just do a quick check on the tag itself (which helps when there is recent activity, just not recent enough). For those people, it probably has some high usability.